# Unable to install the package "email"

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

I can't install the package "email" on Ubuntu 14 neither for Python3, not for Python 2.7

```
 sudo pip install email
 # or sudo pip3 install email
```

And the error is:

```
  ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'

    ----------------------------------------
```

I need to install it for Python3.

Comment: Have you tried importing `email` module directly ? I think it's the part of standard library.

Comment: @Rahul, you're a genius.

Comment: @Rahul, why can't I do this "from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart" ---> "ImportError: No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart'" ?

Comment: Try this `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`email` is an standard library , which need not to be imported separately,

just use `import email`  .

for more usage and features kindly refer to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html)

Comment: Its not included by default in Python 3 for Raspbian OS